# How to List all the Git Repos under Organization, using Groovy?

Tags: git, groovy

Hi I'm new to Groovy and I'm trying to list GitHub repos in my github organization using groovy, but I was able to do it in shell command as given below.

Anyone there to help me to covert this in to groovy ?

```
curl -i -u <user_name>:<tokenID> https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/repos
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors, stacktraces, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use JsonSlurper to parse the results of the URL. For example, if you wanted all the URLs, you'd just do

```
Authenticator.default = new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray())
    }
}
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("https://api.github.com/orgs/myOrg/repos".toURL().text).url
```

Obviously, if it's public repos and org, you don't need the authentication portion.

Comment: Hi Keegan, it's a private repo, and I was trying it in another question but I couldn't find a way of doing that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156222/how-to-create-jenkins-jobs-automatically-in-using-jobdsl-plugin

Comment: I figured it was, and that's what the `Authenticator` portion of the answer is for. I was just saying _if_ it wasn't, you could leave that part out and the rest would work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy, you can execute a shell command easily and get the result like this (assuming curl is accessible):

```
def user = "<user_name>"
def tokenId = "<tokenID>"
def url = "https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/repos"
def command = "curl -i -u $user:#tokenId $url"
println command.execute().text
```